# WebDriver grid configuration throws error

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-grid

I have the following setup:

I am running a grid hub on my local pc with the following config:
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.42.0.jar -role hub -grid1Yml grid_configuration.yml

the config looks like this:

```
hub:
   port: 4444
   remoteControlPollingIntervalInSeconds: 180
   sessionMaxIdleTimeInSeconds: 300
   newSessionMaxWaitTimeInSeconds: 600
   environments:
       - name:    "Firefox on Windows"
         browser: "*firefox"
```

...

I am starting the node via

```
java -jar selenium-server -standalone-2.42.0.jar -role node -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register -port 8888 -browser "browserName=Firefox on windows,maxInstances=1,version=1,platform=WINDOWS"
```

My Test setup looks  like this:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","C:\\IEDriverServer.exe");
        DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
        cap.setBrowserName("*firefox");
        RemoteWebDriver remoteWebDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4444" + "/wd/hub"), cap);

    }
```

If i run my test i get the following error:

```
     Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Error forwarding     
the new session webdriver new session JSON response body did not contain a session ID
Command duration or timeout: 946 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.41.0', revision: '3192d8a6c4449dc285928ba024779344f5423c58', time: '2014-03-27 11:29:39'
System info: host: 'CL-CNU416C97F', ip: '10.11.112.158', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_55'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
```

In the webdriver node i get the important error:
Exception: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.ie.driver system property...

I have set this property via java and in my windows environment. I do not know why i am still getting this error message.

### UPDATE

If i use the grid2 config file (json), how is it possible to set an individual browser by name on each host.

Example:

```
hub:
   port: 4444
   remoteControlPollingIntervalInSeconds: 180
   sessionMaxIdleTimeInSeconds: 300
   newSessionMaxWaitTimeInSeconds: 600
   environments:
       - name:    "MyFireFox on MyMachine1"
         browser: "*firefox"
       - name:    "MyFireFox on MyMachine2"
         browser: "*firefox"
```

If i use this hub config i can start a node by saying it is a "MyFireFox on MyMachine1" Browser. The attribute browser is telling webdriver to use Firefox on the system

If i now use the grid2 config json, i have the following

```
{
 "capabilities": 
    [ 
        {
            "browserName": "MyFireFox on MyMachine1",
            "platform": "WINDOWS",
            "maxInstances": 1
        },
```

but this will not work, because i think the browserName is what browser was in grid1 config.

Answer (score 0):

this is config from my .bat files. also, why do you change your node port to 8888 ? try to remove '-port 8888' and check again

for hub:

```
java -jar path_to_selenium-server-standalone-2.41.0.jar -role hub
```

for node:

```
java -jar path_to_selenium-server-standalone-2.41.0.jar -role node -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register -browser browserName=firefox, platform=WINDOWS
```

here is my json and bat file which 100% works

```
{
 "capabilities": 
    [ 
        {
            "browserName": "firefox",
            "platform": "WINDOWS",
            "maxInstances": 1
        },
        {
            "browserName": "internet explorer",
            "version": "10",
            "platform": "WINDOWS",
            "maxInstances": 1
        }
    ],
    "configuration": 
    { 
        "nodeTimeout":120,
        "port":5555,
        "hubPort":4444,
        "hubHost":"192.168.3.104",
        "nodePolling":2000,
        "registerCycle":10000,
        "register":true,
        "cleanUpCycle":2000,
        "timeout":30000,
        "maxSession":1
    } 
}
```

and bat to start node from json

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.41.0.jar -role node -nodeConfig nodeConfig_win7.json
```

also in system PATH you should add path to folder with drivers for browsers

Comment: The port is used for more than one browser instance on one computer. Why should it help to remove the port? I am using the same command for the hub. I just use an individual config file for the hub to create new possiblities like "Firefox11 on Windows7" , ...

Comment: ok, clear with port. also you can use few -browser options(with different browsers) for one node. did you try example which I provide? Just try to start it from command line and let me know the result.

Comment: Yes of course, i did and this works. This is the setup i used before, but now i want to create my own node setup. It seems that the node is found but for some reason the node itself thinks there should be somehting configured with the internetExplorerDriver, altough i do not use it. It is Firefox that i want to start.

Comment: maybe smthg wrong with json ? I've add my json config above

Comment: Ok you are not using the grid1 config file. Youa re using the grid2 json config. But how is it possible to set a node with an individual browser. I will update my Post to explain my wishes in more detail.

Comment: hmmm. I try to start 2 separate json and for second one I recieve "Unable to access jarfile selenium-server-standalone-2.41.0.jar". So looks like jar is locked by previous grid process. In this case try to use few instances of jar.But better will be to registrer few browsers on one grid, anyway only one browser (which asked by RemoteWebdriver) will be started.